# Append structure to standard table or create Z table?

Tags: abap

Nowadays SAP recommends to "keep the core clean" in order to be able to move to the cloud and always be able to update to the latest version without having to worry or retest, also valid for on-premise.

I got the requirement to add a Z field to the QMEL table to link its notifications to SAP PS projects (PROJ table). The QMEL table already has a structure -CI_QMEL- ready to be extended and the related BAPIs support this extension.

But in order to keep the core clean, I'm considering to challenge the functional requirement and suggest to create a ZNOTIF_PROJ table with the same key than QMEL (Notification ID). This would then become totally separated from the standard but at the same time the official BAPI wouldn't be able to support it, so a wrapper on top would be needed to update the standard and the custom and everything would become more complex.

Should I stick to the old extension style or go for a new table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I prefer extending standard tables.  Having BAPIs, standard transactions, etc, work as expected is worth far more than a nebulous idea like a "clean core."

As long as you're not modding core code or extending tables in an incorrect manner, customizing the system in ways supported by SAP is not a bad thing.  You should consider your future upgrade plans (S/4 on-prem vs cloud, for example) when deciding the right answer, but don't make things too hard on yourself.

Comment: OK, well I'm almost convinced to go this way, but I'm still not sure when a custom field or enhancement can originate problems during an S/4 upgrade. I always extended following SAP recommendations, but still I may have introduced changed that needed to be corrected for big changes like Unicode or HANA db migration. Now I'm in doubt to what extend is it safe to extend the standard and having "automatic" updates at the same time

Comment: This requirement is literally what the CI_QMEL structure is for.  Creating enhancements within the framework that SAP allows you to does not "sully the core".   What SAP means is that you shouldn't create modifications to the core, (the sort of thing that you would need a repair key for, and in some cases implicit enhancements), as that complicates any future upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

S/4 on-prem or cloud already has adding new fields and tables functionality. We can do this in web UI look like SAP CRM. So there is no problem for extending existing structure. Help page about this functionality [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/9a281eac983f4f688d0deedc96b3c61c/1709%20000/en-US/3a713139e548434e8a50800e7a7c8172.html).

Comment: I'm familiar with this functionality because I've seen it in blogs, but since I've never had the chance to try it myself, what is really happening behind? Is the new field added as append structure as in the old times? Or there is an abstraction layer that makes it look like a new field to the table but in reality it's not?  The problem is that I'm still in the old ECC and I would like to implement the cleanest solution ready for a future S/4 migration.

Comment: When user extend existing item, a background job scheduled. This job create new structure and add new custom field on it. Then add new structure to existing. Then add this field on ui5 app. If you upgrade to S/4 in future, your custom field not shown on web UI because of it will on different struct. UI only check struct which name is particular format.